# Derivative of MeijerG function wrt to one of its parameters

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

I would like to evaluate numerically the following expression
$$
\left.\left[\dfrac{\partial}{\partial b}G_{2,4}^{4,0}\left(2\left|\begin{smallmatrix}0&\tfrac{1}{2}\\b&b&b&b\end{smallmatrix}\right.\right)\right]\right|_{b=1/2}.
$$

However, the straightforward

```
D[MeijerG[{{}, {0, 1/2}}, {{b, b, b, b}, {}}, 2], b] /. b -> 1/2
```

returns

```
Derivative[{{}, {0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0, 1}, {}}, 0][
       MeijerG][{{}, {0, 1/2}}, {{1/2, 1/2, 1/2, 1/2}, {}}, 2] + 
   Derivative[{{}, {0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 1, 0}, {}}, 0][
       MeijerG][{{}, {0, 1/2}}, {{1/2, 1/2, 1/2, 1/2}, {}}, 2] + 
   Derivative[{{}, {0, 0}}, {{0, 1, 0, 0}, {}}, 0][
       MeijerG][{{}, {0, 1/2}}, {{1/2, 1/2, 1/2, 1/2}, {}}, 2] + 
   Derivative[{{}, {0, 0}}, {{1, 0, 0, 0}, {}}, 0][
       MeijerG][{{}, {0, 1/2}}, {{1/2, 1/2, 1/2, 1/2}, {}}, 2]
```

Is there a way to get Mathematica actually evaluate the derivative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$Version

(*  "11.0.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (September 21, 2016)"  *)
```

For a numerical approximation use [`ND`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ND.html)

```
Needs["NumericalCalculus`"]

ND[MeijerG[{{}, {0, 1/2}}, {{b, b, b, b}, {}}, 2], b, 1/2]

(*  0.0680074  *)
```

Comment: Great, thank you.